# How do I write a query with a negative boost?

Tags: elasticsearch, searchkick

The ElasticSearch API indicates that you can create [negative boosts](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/not-quite-not.html) to demote results. How does one do this in Searchkick? Do I need to use the [advanced query](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#advanced) tools? Or is there an option somewhere I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth noting that [`function_weight`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-weight) takes a float, so you can using a negative floating point number for a negative boost.

This means that you can use `boost_where` with a negative value to demote a result based on a field.

Comment: I'd mark this as the correct answer (and maybe update with an example). Any `boost_where` with a factor less than 1 should yield a negative boost. Even added a test case for it.

Answer (score 0):

Searchkick doesn't have an option for negative boosts, so you'll need to use advanced querying. I'm happy to accept a pull request for it though.